# Difference of performing calculations with and without using SQL Functions

Tags: sql-server, function

I have this question to write SQL query using function and without using SQL function.
 The employee database is with 2 relations. the primary keys are the employee_name of both tables.The question is to find the company_name whose employees earn a higher salary, on average, than the average salary at "FBC"

employee(employee_name, street, city)
works(employee_name,company_name,salary)

My query without  function is:

```
Declare@AvgSal decimal(10,2),
Declare@AvgSalFBC decimal(10,2),

Select @AvgSal=AVG(salary)
From works w, employee e
Select @AvgSalFBC=AVG(salary)
From works w, where company_name = "FBC" , employee e

ON w.employee_name=e.employee_name

If (@AvgSal>@AvgSalFBC)
Begin
Print w.company_name
End
```

I want to know whether the code is correct and what is the difference writing this with SQL function?

Comment: Does this even work? Syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by SQL Function and SQL without function... But here is some SQL that would return a list of company_names:

```
SELECT w.company_name, avg(e.salary) as average_salary
FROM works w INNER JOIN employee e 
    ON w.employee_name = e.employee_name  
GROUP BY w.company_name  
HAVING average_salary > 
  (
    SELECT avg(e1.salary) 
    FROM works w1 INNER JOIN employee e1 
      ON w1.employee_name = e1.employee_name 
    WHERE w1.company_name = "FBC"
  );
```

Also, joining on employee name seems like a bad idea. Names change and are often poorly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking at the average salaries, then you shouldn't need to use the `employee` table at all. Just **group by** the `company_name` and take the `avg(salary)` from the `works` table. Some code like this might be a good starting point:

```
select company_name, avg(salary)
from works
group by company_name
```

If you want to compare the other companies based on one specific company, you might start by putting these results into a temporary table. Then you can make any further comparisons you want. For example:

```
declare @CompareCompany varchar(50) = 'FBC'

create table #average(company_name varchar(50), avg_salary decimal(14,2))
insert into #average(company_name, avg_salary)
select company_name, avg(salary)
from works
group by company_name

declare @CompareSalary decimal(14,2)
select @CompareSalary = avg_salary 
from #average 
where company_name = @CompareCompany

select company_name, avg_salary
from #average
where avg_salary > @CompareSalary
```

Of course, if you are only wanting the one company with the highest average salary overall, you could always just do this:

```
select top 1 company_name
from works
group by company_name
order by avg(salary) desc
```

I am not sure why you are asking about functions. The data you are talking about is more than a single variable can handle. The only way you can reduce your results to a single function output (or set them to a single variable like you are doing) is if you can guarantee that there will always only be one company that qualifies (like my last example above).